# Ruby: Split and Read part of a file Depending on Thread Count

Tags: ruby, multithreading, csv

I am looking to use multiple threads to speed up a process that is highly I/O bound. I want to be able to call a rest service with IDs taken from a CSV file in a loop. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to elegantly split up the file into chunks depending upon the amount of threads i want to use.

The CSV file contains a single column of ids like so: 
123456789
246802468
987654321
...

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'csv'

FILE_RECORD_COUNT = File.open("path-to-csv","r").readlines.size

def setup(thread_count)
  threads = []
  thread_count.times do
    threads << Thread.new do
      fetches_per_thread = FILE_RECORD_COUNT / thread_count

      fetches_per_thread.times do
        CSV.foreach("id_file.csv") do |id|
          response = RestClient.get("https://api.examplerest/names?id={#id}",{accept: :json})
          # do some quick validation...
        end
      end
    end
  end

  threads.each(&:join)
end

def run_benchmark
  Benchmark.bm(20) do |bm|
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30, 100].each do |thread_count|
      bm.report("with #{thread_count} threads") do
        setup(thread_count)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where I am stumped, and where I need a solution is the code block `CSV.foreach(id_file.csv") do |id|...`. I would like to split up the data dynamically and feed it into each thread, then make a rest call. I know i could split up the file manually but I'd like to avoid that.

I've attempted to make this into a benchmark from an example I found online, to see where the sweet spot is for number of threads.

*EDIT:*
Using BernardK's answer, I was able to run my code threaded and got back the following results:

```
                      |  user   |  system  |   total   |   real   |
with 1 threads         5.125000   2.594000   7.719000 ( 40.416162)
with 2 threads         1.625000   2.015000   3.640000 ( 28.571521)
with 3 threads         1.578000   1.625000   3.203000 ( 17.210526)
with 4 threads         1.578000   1.235000   2.813000 (  8.496068)
with 5 threads         1.406000   1.250000   2.656000 (  6.779216)
with 10 threads        1.875000   1.328000   3.203000 (  5.069487)
with 15 threads        2.016000   1.640000   3.656000 (  4.285426)
with 30 threads        2.125000   1.625000   3.750000 (  3.817084)
with 100 threads       2.281000   1.375000   3.656000 (  3.943304)
```

This was a test run, but really shows how threads like these can speedup Ruby code!

Comment: Please wait, there is an error (`@lines.each_slice` must replace `thread_count.times`).

Comment: @BernardK, okay, when you re-post I will implement your changes and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Done. (the previous version was reading the file `thread_count` times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is read into an array, which is split in chunks using `Enumerable#each_slice`.

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'csv'

@file_name = 'xxx.txt'
file = File.open(@file_name, 'w')
1000.times do | i |
    file.puts "#{i.to_s}"
end
file.close

@lines = []
CSV.foreach(@file_name) { | line | @lines << line }
FILE_RECORD_COUNT = @lines.size
puts FILE_RECORD_COUNT

def setup(thread_count)
  puts "----- thread_count=#{thread_count}"
  threads = []
  fetches_per_thread = FILE_RECORD_COUNT / thread_count
  puts "----- fetches_per_thread=#{fetches_per_thread}"
  raise 'invalid slice size' if fetches_per_thread < 1

  @lines.each_slice(fetches_per_thread) do | slice |
    threads << Thread.new do
      puts "===== slice from #{slice.first} to #{slice.last}"
      slice.each do | id |
#        puts id
#          response = RestClient.get("https://api.examplerest/names/{#id}",{accept: :json})
          # do some quick validation...
      end # slice.each
    end # Thread.new
  end # @lines.each_slice

  threads.each(&:join)
end # def setup

def run_benchmark
  Benchmark.bm(20) do |bm|
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30, 100].each do |thread_count|
      bm.report("with #{thread_count} threads") do
        setup(thread_count)
      end
    end
  end
end

run_benchmark
```

Execution :

```
$ --------------------------------
-bash: --------------------------------: command not found
$ ruby -w t.rb 
1000
                           user     system      total        real
with 1 threads       ----- thread_count=1
----- fetches_per_thread=1000
===== slice from ["0"] to ["999"]
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000288)
with 2 threads       ----- thread_count=2
----- fetches_per_thread=500
===== slice from ["0"] to ["499"]
===== slice from ["500"] to ["999"]
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000318)
with 3 threads       ----- thread_count=3
----- fetches_per_thread=333
===== slice from ["0"] to ["332"]
===== slice from ["666"] to ["998"]
===== slice from ["999"] to ["999"]
===== slice from ["333"] to ["665"]
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000549)
with 5 threads       ----- thread_count=5
----- fetches_per_thread=200
===== slice from ["0"] to ["199"]
===== slice from ["200"] to ["399"]
===== slice from ["400"] to ["599"]
===== slice from ["600"] to ["799"]
===== slice from ["800"] to ["999"]
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000536)
with 6 threads       ----- thread_count=6
----- fetches_per_thread=166
===== slice from ["166"] to ["331"]
===== slice from ["664"] to ["829"]
===== slice from ["830"] to ["995"]
===== slice from ["996"] to ["999"]
===== slice from ["0"] to ["165"]
===== slice from ["332"] to ["497"]
===== slice from ["498"] to ["663"]
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000735)
with 10 threads      ----- thread_count=10
----- fetches_per_thread=100
===== slice from ["900"] to ["999"]
...
===== slice from ["190"] to ["199"]
===== slice from ["200"] to ["209"]
===== slice from ["210"] to ["219"]
===== slice from ["220"] to ["229"]
===== slice from ["230"] to ["239"]
===== slice from ["240"] to ["249"]
...
===== slice from ["970"] to ["979"]
===== slice from ["980"] to ["989"]
===== slice from ["990"] to ["999"]
===== slice from ["20"] to ["29"]
===== slice from ["30"] to ["39"]
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.011656)
```

Then I use the find command in the terminal to find `--------------------------------------` and jump to the beginning of the execution.

Comment: Isn't your benchmark showing that more threads cause it to run slower?

Comment: @Max Isn't it a question for Austin L ? It's his benchmark (showing the best time by 5 threads). I have just helped to split the CSV file into chunks.